# Add response headers and status code to WebResourceResponse

Tags: java, android, webkit, android-webview, response-headers

I'm trying to add response headers and a status code to the WebResourceResponse that I've created locally in the WebView's `shouldInterceptRequest`:

```
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    WebResourceResponse res = createResponse(...);
    res.setResponseHeaders(...)
    res.setStatusCodeAndReasonPhrase(...)
    return res;
}
```

Now this works on Lollipop devices and above.

However, I'd like to do this on **Pre-Lollipop** devices in `public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {`. Unfortunately the `setResponseHeaders()` and `setStatusCodeAndReasonPhrase()` is not available on pre-Lollipop devices. Is there a workaround for this?  How does pre-Lollipop devices handle headers and status codes? There must've been a way prior to the new API right?

Thanks,